# Unable to maintain data inside gridview across postback when used inside an user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, viewstate

I've a textbox that is present inside a GridView that itself is a part of user control and I'm dynamically loading this user control on page_Init.

The controls in my user control are a DropDown, a TextBox and a GridView.

Now DropDown and TextBox are able to retain values across postback but textboxes inside the GridView are not retaining the values.

Adding User Control on page init:

```
 if (postBackCntrl.Contains("AddUserControlButton"))
            {
                UserControl newGrid = (UserControl)LoadControl("~/UserControl.ascx");
                newGrid.ID = "test" + gridList.Count;
                gridList.Add(newGrid);
            }
```

GridView Code: TextBoxes inside GridView ItemTemplate not able to retain values across postback:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdUser" CssClass="GridTable" Width="90%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                ShowFooter="true" OnDataBound="MergeGridViewFooter">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContactUs">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactUs" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Height="60px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnaddrow" runat="server" Text="Add Row" CssClass="ui-button jquery-ui" Style="font-size: 12px" OnClick="btnaddrow_Click" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelRowAddress" runat="server" Text="Delete Row" CssClass="ui-button jquery-ui" Style="font-size: 12px" OnClick="btnDelRowAddress_Click" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Definition">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDefinition" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="60px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="60px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the valuable suggestion, but instead of focusing on secondary stuff , you could have helped me on this.

Comment: Whether I help or not is immaterial - the link is a reminder that the time of volunteers should be respected, and requests for special treatment are not likely to garner the speedy response you desire.

Comment: Is your user control create code running every time, even on post-back?  It would be much easier to put the user control on the page, then hide/show it based on logic rather than loading dynamically.

Comment: @Seano666  I don't need a single control on the page, I need to create it multiple times on button click, so keeping it on page won't for me